# Undefined index stripeToken

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments

I have a stripe checkout error in my symfony project. Here is my view that uses checkout by default :

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_C9N5xzeBHyGplmZwpsbyciS6"
            data-amount="9999"
            data-name="Demo Site"
            data-description="Widget"
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-zip-code="true"
            data-currency="eur">
    </script>
</form>
```

The method of my controller:

```
public function paiementAction(Request $request)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_5W9Z1CdBKN2G46sTa2O5KI3T");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 1000, // Amount in cents
            "currency" => "eur",
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => "Example charge"
        ));
        return $this->redirectToRoute("chk38_platform_confirmation");
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // The card has been declined

        return $this->redirectToRoute("chk38_platform_commande");
    }

}`
```

[Error Symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VNTl.png)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why would you use PHP's global? Instead, use `Request` instance. For example: `$request->request->get('stripeToken')`

Comment: I have already tried this way but I still have this error:

[link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=411187error.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue of `$_POST['stripeToken']` not being populated generally occurs when your code isn't creating a `Token` object via Stripe Checkout prior to running this bit of code.

I would suggest that you check your Stripe account's API logs (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/overview) and ensure that you are in fact correctly creating a `Token` object via Stripe Checkout prior to calling this create `Charge` snippet.

You may also want to read through their Checkout PHP tutorial (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php), to get a better understanding of how all of the pieces fit together. If you still have issues after all that, you may want to write in to their support staff via https://support.stripe.com/email since you probably don't want to discuss private account specific things in public.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick finding I just experienced. If you're using the default `<form action="/directory" method="POST"> ... </form>` from this [stripe example page](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart) with your own endpoint make sure to specify down to the `index.php` file inside the directory folder.

I was getting an odd error where the token was being created but I would get directed to the PHP endpoint and it wasn't a POST event. I had an `index.php` file in `/directory/` and I had to write the complete path not just up to `/directory` eg. `/directory/index.php`. Then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm and extend what subalublub said, in that the endpoint can simply be "/charge/" without having to use index.php there.

I ran into this issue and just using "/charge" was not passing in the $_POST values, but when changing to "/charge/" the index.php file inside that folder worked correctly.

Hope this helps someone.